# EV3 brick not turning on, nothing on display?

Tags: ev3, repair

Ev3 brick not turning on, nothing on display, just red leds are on, tried 3 buttons not working.

Answer (score 2):

Each time I experienced what you are describing, replacing the batteries with fully charged ones addressed the issue...

Comment: I add the same problem. Hitting the central button would only turn on the red light and they would start blinking. As Michael said, replacing the batteries with brand new ones solved the problem. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing the 'return' button along with the center button for about 5 seconds